# From simple desktop application to client server application

Tags: c#, wcf, client-server, desktop-application

I have developed a simple desktop application with a SQL Server database for a single PC and now the client want to make it work on multiple PCs. I want to know what is better: for the moment I have remote the database from sql management and all application just connect to it. Is this a good idea or do I have to do some modification to improve the executing of the application?

- The database has a lot of information to be imported to the application.
- I don’t have a good idea about WCF but would it help to read about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a dedicated server with database hosted on it and all the client applications could connect to it. But one thing you have to take care of is `transaction` management that is while a user is updating some piece of information, no other user could change that piece of data to make that data inconsistent. You could a look at this post describiing [Sql Server Transactions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqlservertransactions.aspx).

Comment: you say that I let the application just it look like now just i have to take care about transaction management ??

Comment: Yeah you have to do transaction management if you want to move you application from single user to multiple user. Please tell the scope of your application, how many users you need to support, how critical is the data etc etc

Comment: the application will support between 10 and 20 users and the data not critical

Comment: I guess you dont need to do much from moving you application to multiple users from single user as you said data is not critical. You might have to do transaction management to make data consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the requirements I'd recommend keeping the local database as cache for speedy application start and implement a synchronisation process where the local and remote databases are compared from time to time or triggered manually by the user.

This would be very similar to how for example IMAP email clients or Evernote works.

Comment: for the moment the database is located in a server... you mean that I keep a local base in each PC but the synchronisation done with c# code or with sqlserver ?

Comment: not sure what's the best way to do the synching, but keeping a local database is going to help a lot with synch conflict resolution and concurrence, if you let everyone to work on the same remote database there's going to be inevitable lockups like Abdul mentioned, or you'll have to do an awful lot of work to make it smooth and it's going to be a nightmare to debug!